# HTML5 equivalent of FontFace / FontFace.load

Tags: javascript, html, fonts

I've been using JavaScript to load my fonts using:

```
    this.myFont = new FontFace(name, path);
    this.myFont.load().then(function(font)
    {
        document.fonts.add(font);
        loadcomplete = true;
        console.log("FONT LOADED");
    });
```

Unfortunately, Internet Explorer doesn't appear to support this the Javascript FontFace API. So it it possible to load the installable TTF/WOFF via CCS and HTML instead and reference the font from JS? I've looked at a few samples but most seem to use the font in the HTML rather than JS.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver, https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-events.html

Comment: I'm confused by the title. What do you mean by HTML5 equivalent? If you need a polyfill for the FontFace AP check @CBroe's comment.

Comment: I thought there's a HTML5 equivalent of doing what the JavaScript FontFace loader does, by using CSS and HTML to create an element that I could get font information from.